# Runtime Error when using interpretor.invoke() on Raspberry PI

Tags: tensorflow, raspberry-pi, tensorflow-lite, raspberry-pi4, tflite

I am trying to run a tflite object detection model on my raspberry pi 4, and i get the following error :

```
 RuntimeError : ConcatOp : Can't concatenate scalars (use tf.stack instead) Node number 43565 (TfLiteFlexDelefate) failed to invoke.ConcatOp
```

Here is the code I'm using :

```
# Load the label map into memory
with open(PATH_TO_LABELS, 'r') as f:
    labels = [line.strip() for line in f.readlines()]

# Load the Tensorflow Lite model into memory
interpreter = Interpreter(model_path=MODEL_DETECTION_PATH)
interpreter.resize_tensor_input(0,(1,600,800,3))
interpreter.allocate_tensors()

# Get model details
input_details = interpreter.get_input_details()
output_details = interpreter.get_output_details()


cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    start = time.perf_counter()
    ret, image = cap.read()

    image_resized = cv2.resize(image,(800,600))
    
    # Expand dimensions since the model expects images to have shape: [1, 600, 300, 3]
    input_image = np.expand_dims(image_resized, axis=0)

    interpreter.set_tensor(input_details[0]['index'],input_image)
    interpreter.invoke()

    boxes = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[1]['index'])[0] # Bounding box coordinates of detected objects
    scores = interpreter.get_tensor(output_details[0]['index'])[0] # Confidence of detected objects
```

I'm using tensorflow 2.12, and I can't figure out what's wrong with my code...

Input_details are

```
[{'name': 'serving_default_input_tensor:0',
  'index': 0,
  'shape': array([  1, 600, 800,   3], dtype=int32),
  'shape_signature': array([ 1, -1, -1,  3], dtype=int32),
  'dtype': numpy.uint8,
  'quantization': (0.0, 0),
  'quantization_parameters': {'scales': array([], dtype=float32),
   'zero_points': array([], dtype=int32),
   'quantized_dimension': 0},
  'sparsity_parameters': {}}]
```

And I have those info printing when allocating tensors :

```
INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite delegate for select TF ops.
INFO: TfLiteFlexDelegate delegate: 6 nodes delegated out of 43563 nodes with 3 partitions.

INFO: Created TensorFlow Lite XNNPACK delegate for CPU.
```